# How to increase the width of a carousel without changing the responsiveness of an website

Tags: html, css

I used the width property in

## carouselExampleControls{

width:1400px;

left:-270px;

}
but the entire size of the website is changing. [as shown in figure I need this full website width carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kd6v.jpg)I need to increase the width of the carousel only.

pasting my entire code here:

```
<!-- Required meta tags -->

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">



<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



<title>Hello, world!</title>
```

body {

margin: 0;

font-size: 28px;

font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

}

.content {

padding: 16px;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar {

```
display: none;
```

}

.content{

width:1000px;

margin:0 auto;

}

## carouselExampleControls{

}

.card{

border:none;

}

.card-body{

```
font-family: ProximaNova-Semibold,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;

font-size: 18px;

font-weight: 600;

font-style: normal;

font-stretch: normal;

letter-spacing: normal;

color: #4a4a4a;
```

}

h2 {

```
display: block;

font-size:30px;

margin-block-start:40px;

margin-block-end:20px;

margin-inline-start:0px;

margin-inline-end: 0px;

font-weight:bold;
```

font-style: normal;

font-stretch: normal;

letter-spacing: normal;

}

.slide-box img {

-ms-flex: 0 0 25%;

```
flex: 0 0 25%;

max-width: 45%;
```

padding-left:20px;

}

.slide-box {

justify-content: space-between;

}

Link

  

  

    Link

  

  

    Disabled

  







  

  

    

      Mains

    

    

      Meals on offer

    



      Biriyanis

    



      Appetisers

    



      Fit N Fab

    



  









   

  

    

      

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

        



    

    

      

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

          



    

    

      

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       





            

              

              

            

       



   

            

          





      

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



            

             

    



      

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

             

    



      

            

              

              

            

       



   

            

              

              

            

       





            

              

              

            

       



   

            

          







  



  

    

    Previous

  

  

    

    Next

### Mains

Thai Minced Chicken Rice Bowl

₹180 ₹220 18% OFF.

1656 favs 200+ bought today















  Gusteau - Smoked Ratatouille Burrito

  ₹200

  Available from 6:00PM

  30 favs-90+ bought today















  Peppy Paprika Burrito

  ₹200

   Available from 6:00PM

  33 favs 100+ bought today





















Black Bean Veggies Hakka Noodles

₹160 ₹200 20% OFF

910 favs 150+ bought today















  Peri Peri Chicken 'n' Quinoa Olive Rice

  ₹180 ₹230 22% OFF

  Available from 6:00PM

  1315 favs 500+ bought today















Jaipuri Kofta 'n' Laccha Paratha

  ₹170 ₹200 15% OFF

  379 favs 150+ bought today

### Biriyanis

Thai Minced Chicken Rice Bowl

₹180 ₹220 18% OFF.

1656 favs 200+ bought today















  Gusteau - Smoked Ratatouille Burrito

  ₹200

  Available from 6:00PM

  30 favs-90+ bought today















  Peppy Paprika Burrito

  ₹200

   Available from 6:00PM

  33 favs 100+ bought today





















Black Bean Veggies Hakka Noodles

₹160 ₹200 20% OFF

910 favs 150+ bought today















  Peri Peri Chicken 'n' Quinoa Olive Rice

  ₹180 ₹230 22% OFF

  Available from 6:00PM

  1315 favs 500+ bought today















Jaipuri Kofta 'n' Laccha Paratha

  ₹170 ₹200 15% OFF

  379 favs 150+ bought today

### Appetisers

Thai Minced Chicken Rice Bowl

₹180 ₹220 18% OFF.

1656 favs 200+ bought today















  Gusteau - Smoked Ratatouille Burrito

  ₹200

  Available from 6:00PM

  30 favs-90+ bought today















  Peppy Paprika Burrito

  ₹200

   Available from 6:00PM

  33 favs 100+ bought today

























Black Bean Veggies Hakka Noodles

₹160 ₹200 20% OFF

910 favs 150+ bought today















  Peri Peri Chicken 'n' Quinoa Olive Rice

  ₹180 ₹230 22% OFF

  Available from 6:00PM

  1315 favs 500+ bought today















Jaipuri Kofta 'n' Laccha Paratha

  ₹170 ₹200 15% OFF

  379 favs 150+ bought today

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->

<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Just give the Carousel a `width: 100vw`

Comment: Have you tried to target the specific element that you wish to do a width on, and work in percent rather than pixels? percentage based width should keep the carousel responsiveness intact.

Comment: Tried that. I need only carousel element in the full width of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you posted can be fixed using `width: 100%;` on the `.content` element and `width: 100%` on the `.carousel`. It is a quick fix, but it works for your issue.

Comment: I tried this. But the food menu list will be not responsive in mobile view. I can't edit the width of the content class.

Comment: Do you mean the navigation at the top? I can't find a element named food menu

Comment: Sorry..!Yes, I mean the navigation at the top

Comment: How do you want the navigation to behave? When I apply the styles I mentioned in my answer, the navigation points break into multiple lines. Do you want the nav to stay in one line without breaking?

Comment: Yes, sir. I need the nav to stay in one line without breaking.

Comment: You can remove the `flex-wrap: wrap;` from the `.nav`, add `overflow-x: scroll` to the  `.navbar` add `white-space: nowrap` to the `nav-link`, but the items won't move to the center if you scroll the page. You would need some JavaScript to add that functionality

Comment: I suggest to get the page to work on small screens and try to fix the nav afterwards. If your attempt doesn't work, you can ask another specific question for your navigation. Maybe try to provide a minimal code example next time, that shows your problem, so it's easier for others to help you

Comment: I tried this. But navigation points break into multiple lines in mobile view

Comment: Okay.Thank you :)